# How to upgrade Node js version to 0.12.4 on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I want to upgrade Node JS version on Ubuntu.

I tried many commands but its version is still the older i.e v0.10.37.

I tried:

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n install 0.12.4
sudo n use 0.12.4
```

Also tried with nvm but non of them works for me. How can I upgrade Node Js version to 0.12.4?

Comment: It might be a problem with the `PATH` variable. The path where `n` installs/activated node might not be included, or in the wring order.

Answer (score 9):

Use **npm** in order to upgrade **node**

First Clean the cache and try

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 0.12.4
```

Then create a symbolic link(It is needed only sometimes, first try with these three commands. If it doesnot work add this.)

It will be updated to `0.12.4` Version.

Comment: I tried it , after the execution of last command it is showing Error: invalid version 0.12.4

Comment: You need 0.12.4  or stable one? If you need stable one, `sudo n stable`

Answer (score 4):

It could be enough just to install `n` module:

`sudo npm install -g n`

and then simply run:

`sudo n 0.12.4`

The trick is that it may not be updated in your current terminal session. So you can simply open one more tab in your terminal or just another terminal and check your nodejs version by:

`node --version`

That's it, output will be `v0.12.4`

Comment: Thanks for the trick: I thought I was going to get crazy but it was actually updated...

Comment: This also worked for me! Sadly, `nvm` was extremely annoying to setup on an old AWS instance, but using `n` made this quick and dirty for an end-of-life product.

Answer (score 1):

The official doc from nodejs repository points to this : https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories#installing-node-js-v0-12

Just follow it and you'll have the 0.12.4.

Comment: I tried that too using apt-get command, it say nodejs is already the newest version. When I check version it say v0.10.37

Comment: Can you show the output of `grep -h ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

Comment: You don't have the source list from the blog I posted but you have a nodejs ppa.
Remove it with `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ppa:chris-lea/node.js` and add the new one : `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -`.
After that you can install nodejs `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Comment: Repaste your source.list, I'm sure you don't have `https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.12`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80014/discussion-between-pierre-inglebert-and-hassan-sardar).

Comment: http://pastebin.ca/3022608 This is what I get when I run curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -

Answer (score 1):

Try running this in terminal:

```
nvm install 5.10.1
nvm use 5.10.1
```

The version may be change.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Execute following comand to upgrade nodejs to 0.12.x

## Note the new setup script name for Node.js v0.12

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -

## Then install with:

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

Just ignore warning. By executing both commands it worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: after executing this nodejs remains in same version

Answer (score 0):

On **Ubuntu 16.04**

There is no special or dedicated comand to upgrade node version. The correct way to install or upgrade node on ubuntu is:

1) download the distribution you wish from [nodejs official site](http://nodejs.org/dist/), move the file into a known path

2) open a terminal and run: >`sudo tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xzf "known path/name_of_the_distribution_file...gz`

3) test if everything is ok: open a new terminal and run `node --version`. It should echo the version you downloaded and installed/upgraded.