# Unable to install of latest version of nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I was having nodejs version 4.2.6 in my ubuntu 16.04 pc.
I tried to install n using command `sudo npm install -g n`, and the following errors came out.

```
Node.js 4 is supported but the specific version you're running has
```

a bug known to break npm. Please update to at least 4.7.0 to use this
version of npm. You can find the latest release of Node.js at https://nodejs.org/

I uninstalled the current nodejs and then reinstalled it .But everytime the version 4.2.6 is installed.I am not getting why the latest version is not installed.I followed this link to reinstall my nodejs
[enter link description here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Do i need any others updated to have latest nodejs ?Please guide me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723507/how-to-upgrade-node-js-version-to-0-12-4-on-ubuntu/35716111#35716111

Comment: I don,t know why someone vote my question as not useful. If something is unclear you should ask to make things clear. I resolved my problem without the help of stackoverflow. I found my solution here. [https://askubuntu.com/questions/786272/why-does-installing-node-6-x-on-ubuntu-16-04-actually-install-node-4-2-6].
This is for those who go through this problem .Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Here are the steps to follow:**

> 1. First clear cache.
> 2. Then upgrade `npm`
> 3. Then install stable version if Node

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

If that still didt work

> 1. Remove NodeJs and Npm
> 2. Install Node

```
sudo apt remove nodejs npm
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: $ sudo npm cache clean -f
ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v4.2.6
Node.js 4 is supported but the specific version you're running has
a bug known to break npm. Please update to at least 4.7.0 to use this
version of npm. You can find the latest release of Node.js at https://nodejs.org/

This is the output its showing

Comment: I updated the answer. Please follow those steps once.

Answer (score 1):

You can install latest version of nodejs by adding local apt repo as mention in [official doc](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions),

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

and then use `n` or `nvm` module to manage version.

**Update:** You should uninstall older version before installing newer version

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: I have followed these steps very seriously but every time the same version is installed ,i.e not the latest version .its 4.2.6 and its clainming it to be the latest version.

Comment: uninstall and then try to install, I also updated answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use nvm and install severall version of node and switch on node version

this link help you

[enter link description here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)

Answer (score 0):

use NVM to manage all node versions